# Headphones-like ear warmers?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call the thing some people use to keep their ears warm that looks like fluffy headphones?

Comment: Heh, I thought you were asking about earmuffs that have headphones built in.  I had a pair of those; I wonder if I could still find them...

Comment: @PeterCordes Those would be "earmuff-like headphones".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Earmuffs** — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earmuffs)

> Earmuffs are objects designed to cover a person's ears for protection or for warmth. They consist of a thermoplastic or metal head-band, that fits over the top or back of the head, and a pad at each end, to cover the external ears.

Comment: Added a reference on your behalf.